# deserialize object from xml gives error: 'Memory stream is not expandable'

Tags: c#, serialization

i re-used some old code (i think an older .net version) which is used to deserialize an object from xml (at the end i'll paste the code which i used to serialize the object)

this is the code:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Reconstruct an object from an XML string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xml"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string xml)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(StringToUTF8ByteArray(xml)))
            using (new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
```

it gives me this error: `'Memory stream is not expandable`' at the return line.

What went wrong?

this is the serialize code:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            using (XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(item.GetType());
                xs.Serialize(xml, item);
                stream = (MemoryStream)xml.BaseStream;
            }

            return UTF8ByteArrayToString(stream.ToArray());
```

EDIT

this is the missing function

```
private static Byte[] StringToUTF8ByteArray(string pXmlString)
        {
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(pXmlString);
            return byteArray;
        }
```

Comment: What's the point of this:  `using (new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))`?

Comment: Why are you creating the `XmlTextWriter`?

Comment: good questions about the xmltextwriter, but to be honoust: it's from an older project, and i only know it worked back then, i don't know how it works....

Answer (score 7):

First you're creating a `MemoryStream` to *read* from the XML. You're then creating an `XmlTextWriter` to *write* to that stream. Why?

I suspect you can  just get rid of the second using statement:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(StringToUTF8ByteArray(xml)))
{
    return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Having said that, it's not at all clear what your `StringToUTF8ByteArray` method does - is it just:

```
return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

? If so, that may well *not* be the right thing to do - if the original XML was in some other encoding, then the XML declaration will say one thing and the stream will contain text encoded in another encoding... not good. You might be better off with:

```
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(reader));
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon, the original objects are serialized with utf8, so i think that will be ok. For your first 'why'? To behonoust, i've never fully understood streams. So when i see some good looking and working serialize / deserialize code, i'll just use it as a blackbox. That works fine for some things, until it breaks :-)

Comment: @Michel: Yeah, don't do that. It's well worth investing the time in working out how streams (and readers and writers) work conceptually. They're so important, they're best *not* left for cut and paste code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need an XmlTextReader possibly instead of an XmlTextWriter?  I am using this to serialize to a file.  You might want to use something similar:

```
/// <summary>
/// Serialize an object into XML and save to a file
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="value"></param>
/// <param name="filePath"></param>
public static void SerializeToXml<T>(T value, string filePath) where T : class
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        x.Serialize(stream, value);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Deserialize an XML File into an object
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string filePath) where T : class
{
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)x.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm really bad at streams, what would this be when i want to do the same but then with a (xml) string in stead of a file?